# Jenkins job stucks at the end after running all unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, uwp, mstest, jenkins-mstest

The Jenkins executes all unit tests but in the end I'm getting this message in output:

...
Passed   test_name...
Closing app with package full name 'app_full_name'.
The active test run was aborted. Reason: One or more errors occurred.
Closing app with package full name 'app_full_name'
...

I dont know what is happening, what are this "errors", I think maybe the problem is that Jenkins coud not close the UI window opened by UWP Unit Test App, but I'm not sure. Any ideia?

Comment: The error message is from mstest - so one or more tests was unsuccessful.

Comment: I have the same problem. Examining the logs output from the `/Diag` switch it seems a permissions exception is thrown internally when it tries to kill the process.